# Netbeans: "unable to resolve identifier string"

Tags: c++, netbeans

This has to be a bug (the error in the title), but does anyone know how to fix it or just get around it?

Here is the code (I also have two other files which are having the same problem):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(): name(""), dob(""), gender("") { }
    Person(string n, string d, string g): name(n), dob(d), gender(g) { }
    virtual void print() { cout << name << " " << dob << endl; }
protected:
    string name;
    string dob;
    string gender;
};
```

Every instance of "string" in the code above receives the "unable to resolve identifier string" error.

It also is not able to resolve the identifier "cout" and "endl."  Again, does anyone know a workaround or some kind of fix?  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which _'bugs'_ in particular please? Be specific!

Comment: What do you mean?  The error is "unable to resolve identifier string"

Comment: Show exact compiler errors (including line numbers etc.) as you get them, to have useful answers applied here!

Answer (score 6):

`cout`, `endl`, and `string` are not in the global namespace. They are inside `std`.

You need to use `std::cout`, `std::endl`, `std::string` instead.

If you want to avoid appending `std::` every time, you can use `using`.

Put these after the includes:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Sorry, stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `cout`, `string`, and `endl` are all symbols defined in the namespace `std`. If you do not qualify them or introduce those names into the local or enclosing namespace they will be not be found by the compiler. To qualify them, prepend the name `std::`. For example,

```
protected:
    std::string name;
    std::string dob;
    std::string gender;
```

You would also do the same for other standard names. Another option is to use a `using` statement, like this:

```
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

You also might be tempted to use `using namespace std`, but for several reasons this usage is deemed a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Do not use it.